# Lodash filter and omit

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

Is there a way I can filter on an array, but omit certain key:values using lodash? For example:

```js
var people = [{
    _id: 0,
    name: 'Joe',
    type: 1
}, {
    _id: 1,
    name: 'James',
    type: 2
}, {
    _id: 2,
    name: 'Mary',
    type: 0
}, {
    _id: 3,
    name: 'Clark',
    type: 0
}];

var people_with_type_0 = _.filter(people, { 'type': 0 });

// so people_with_type_0 now contains the following
var people_with_type_0 = [{
    _id: 2,
    name: 'Mary',
    type: 0
}, {
    _id: 3,
    name: 'Clark',
    type: 0
}];
```

The above is brilliant, but I want to omit the type?

Comment: Browser support? Tagged as node.js...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

people_with_type_0 can be pass through _.map() to get the objects without 'type' property:

```
var array = _.map(people_with_type_0, function(person) {
  return _.omit(person, 'type');
});
console.log(array);
```

This prints:

```
[ 
  { _id: 2, name: 'Mary' }, 
  { _id: 3, name: 'Clark' } 
]
```

Comment: Do you have an answer for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496966/mysql-like-query-result-using-loadsh-from-json-array

Answer (score 3):

```
_.map(_.filter(people,{type : 0}),_.partial(_.omit,_,'type'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a chained call for something like this. Use [filter()](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) to get what you need, then [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) to transform the results.

```
_(people)
  .filter({ type: 0 })
  .map(_.unary(_.partialRight(_.omit, 'type')))
  .value();
```