# Mysql like query result using lodash from json array

Tags: php, json, lodash

I have JSON look like this

```
[{"id":"7","name":"hello","username":"hell7s692","password":"dAggzyFMnBXq3RjoTWoJ3ndBkGhyU6njT2ZPlNfXVV8+XU3vvrTaULUAbPcmsqgj1NpXOpzieKRXWox\/BVcYrA==","email":"hello@gmail.com","mobile_number":"7736527089","address":"hello","date":"24 Jan 2016 12:14:02","active":"1","commission":"5"},
{"id":"7","name":"hello","username":"hell7s692","password":"dAggzyFMnBXq3RjoTWoJ3ndBkGhyU6njT2ZPlNfXVV8+XU3vvrTaULUAbPcmsqgj1NpXOpzieKRXWox\/BVcYrA==","email":"hello@gmail.com","mobile_number":"7736527089","address":"hello","date":"24 Jan 2016 12:14:02","active":"1","commission":"5"}
]
```

From this i want to get the new json  that matches the condition  in like query

ie i want to get the json with  the condition

**get all the json object with name start with  a letter**

Similar mysql query  `where name like he%`

Currently i know about only `matches` but it returns the array with only exact match.

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false }
];

_.filter(users, _.matches({ 'age': 40, 'active': false }));
// → [{ 'user': 'fred', 'age': 40, 'active': false }]
```

This will returns with only exact match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using _.matches(), you can use _.startsWith() to match the first n-characters you need to.  For example, if you want to match name starting with 'he', you can do something like this:

```
var result = [{
  name: 'hello'
}, {
  name: 'healthy'
}];

_.filter(result, function(obj) {
  return _.startsWith(obj.name, 'he');
});
```

This should match both.

You can also use regular expression to match them:

```
_.filter(result, function(obj) {
    return obj.name.search(/he/i) === 0;  // i = ignore case
});
```

'i' in '/he/i' means ignore case, so this will match name = 'Hello' also.

search() returns the 1st position of the pattern it found, it returns -1 if not found.  So if you need to find a pattern anywhere in a string instead of starting from the beginning, you can check for search() >= 0.  So

```
_.filter(result, function(obj) {
    return obj.name.search(/he/i) >= 0;
});
```

will match 'hello', 'shell', 'healthy', 'the', and etc

Comment: getting this error `_.startsWith is not a function`

Comment: I think startsWith() is lodash 4.x.  You're probably using 3.x. 'npm update lodash' to update lodash

Comment: But my version is 4.3.0

Comment: for case insensitive, you need to use regular expression like I have for 2nd solution in the answer.  Or do this   return _.startsWith(obj.name.toLowerCase(), 'he');

Comment: Can i concatenate a variable instead of letter?

Comment: Bcz thats a keyword from user

Comment: `obj.name.search(/he/i) === 0; ` instead of `he` it should be variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103934/discussion-between-ben-and-shammon).

Comment: Hai @ben  do you have an answer for this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35519293/getting-new-array-of-objects-that-matches-multple-values-in-json