# Lodash:Getting new array with mulitple matches in JSON

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, lodash

I have a nested JSON look like this

```
[
{arrivalTime: "10:30 PM"
 availableSeats: 23
boardingPoints: [{id: "3882"
location: "abc"
time: "02:30PM"},{id: "3882"
location: "xyz"
time: "02:30PM"}]
busType: "Scania Metrolink"
commPCT: 8
departureTime: "1:15 PM"
droppingPoints: null
},
{arrivalTime: "10:30 PM"
 availableSeats: 23
boardingPoints: [{id: "3882"
location: "def"
time: "02:30PM"},{id: "3882"
location: "jkl"
time: "02:30PM"}]
busType: "Scania "
commPCT: 8
departureTime: "1:15 PM"
droppingPoints: null
}    
]
```

From this i want to get new array that matches a condtion.
Here is it

1.get the new array with only the user specified  `location` in `boardingPoints` object.

eg-a:Suppose the location value is `xyz` it will return only the JSON with 
 that contains the location `xyz` only in  the `boardingPoints` object.

**output**

*{arrivalTime: "10:30 PM"
 availableSeats: 23
boardingPoints: [{id: "3882"
location: "abc"
time: "02:30PM"},{id: "3882"
location: "**xyz**"
time: "02:30PM"}]
busType: "Scania Metrolink"
commPCT: 8
departureTime: "1:15 PM"
droppingPoints: null
}*

eg-b:Suppose location value is `xyz` and `def` it should returns only with JSON that contains the above two locations  only in  the `boardingPoints` object.

**output**

*{arrivalTime: "10:30 PM"
 availableSeats: 23
boardingPoints: [{id: "3882"
location: "abc"
time: "02:30PM"},{id: "3882"
location: "**xyz**"
time: "02:30PM"}]
busType: "Scania Metrolink"
commPCT: 8
departureTime: "1:15 PM"
droppingPoints: null
},
{arrivalTime: "10:30 PM"
 availableSeats: 23
boardingPoints: [{id: "3882"
location: "**def**"
time: "02:30PM"},{id: "3882"
location: "jkl"
time: "02:30PM"}]
busType: "Scania "
commPCT: 8
departureTime: "1:15 PM"
droppingPoints: null
}*

I know this may be implemented using `lodash` but i don't know how to do it

Currently i know about only matches in `lodash` but i don't know how can i use this in my case.

```
    var users = [
      { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
      { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false }
    ];  
    _.filter(users, _.matches({ 'age': 40}));
// → [{ 'user': 'fred', 'age': 40, 'active': false }]
```

Is it possible with native method in javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a series of lodash calls with some logic to get the expected results.  Something like this:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var result = [
    {
        arrivalTime: "10:30 PM",
        availableSeats: 23,
        boardingPoints: [{
            id: "3882",
            location: "abc",
            time: "02:30PM"
        },{
            id: "3882",
            location: "xyz",
            time: "02:30PM"
        }],
        busType: "Scania Metrolink",
        commPCT: 8,
        departureTime: "1:15 PM",
        droppingPoints: null,
    },
    {
        arrivalTime: "10:30 PM",
        availableSeats: 23,
        boardingPoints: [{
            id: "3882",
            location: "def",
            time: "02:30PM"
        },{
            id: "3882",
            location: "jkl",
            time: "02:30PM"
        }],
        busType: "Scania ",
        commPCT: 8,
        departureTime: "1:15 PM",
        droppingPoints: null
    }
];
var locations = ['xyz'];

var f = _.filter(result, function(obj) {
    var value = _.map(obj.boardingPoints, 'location');       
    var i, len;

    for (i = 0, len = locations.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (_.indexOf(value, locations[i]) >= 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
});

console.log(f);  // result is your eg-a
```

when

```
locations = ['xyz', 'def'];
```

the result will be your eg-b

**Another approach to the solution is to chain the calls with intersection():**

```
var f = _.filter(result, function(obj) {
  return _.chain(obj.boardingPoints).map('location').intersection(locations).value().length > 0;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: One more question suppose the json is this `{name:'aa',age:20},
{name:'bb',age:21},
{name:'cc',age:21},
{name:'dd',age:24}` and i want to get the rows that matches with multple name

Comment: eg: if names are aa and bb the output becomes

{name:'aa',age:20},
{name:'bb',age:21}

Comment: How can i modify the above to get this

Comment: that problem seems like this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496966/mysql-like-query-result-using-loadsh-from-json-array/35500125?noredirect=1#comment58728842_35500125

Comment: I just founded you from this question:)

Comment: you can just do:  return _.includes(['aa', 'bb'], obj.name);   in the filter

Comment: Suppose   i have another object `dropingPoints` in the question with same key as `BoardingPoints` object but values are different.now i need the json    both matches `location` in the `DroppingPoint` and `BoardingPoint` So how can i get this ?

Comment: This seems different from the original question.  It's probably best to put in another post since it could confuse other readers if I try to modify add another answer to this post's answer.

Comment: Ok  I am gonna put new question about this issue

Comment: This is my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592988/lodashgetting-new-array-with-multiple-key-value-matches-in-json

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = _.filter(yourArray, function(item) {
    return _.size(_.intersection(['xyz', 'def'], _.map(item.boardingPoints, 'location')));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qeaabov9/2/

Comment: do you have answer for this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592988/lodashgetting-new-array-with-multiple-key-value-matches-in-json