# Lodash:Getting new array with multiple key-value matches in json

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

I have nessted JSON look like this

```
[
    {arrivalTime: "10:30 PM"
     availableSeats: 23
    boardingPoints: [{id: "3882"
    location: "abc"
    time: "02:30PM"},{id: "3882"
    location: "xyz"
    time: "02:30PM"}]
    busType: "Scania Metrolink"
    operatorName:"sham"
    commPCT: 8
    departureTime: "1:15 PM"
    droppingPoints: [{id: "3882"
    location: "dex"
    time: "02:30PM"},{id: "3882"
    location: "afg"
    time: "02:30PM"}]
    },
    {arrivalTime: "10:30 PM"
     availableSeats: 23
    boardingPoints: [{id: "3882"
    location: "def"
    time: "02:30PM"},{id: "3882"
    location: "jkl"
    time: "02:30PM"}]
    busType: "Scania "
    operatorName:"manu"
    commPCT: 8
    departureTime: "1:15 PM"
    droppingPoints: [{id: "3882"
    location: "ccd"
    time: "02:30PM"},{id: "3882"
    location: "eef"
    time: "02:30PM"}]
    }
    ]
```

From this i want to get new array that matches the these `key` values.
Here is the keys.

1.BoardingPoints.

2.DroppingPoints.

3.busType.

4.OperatorName.

Eg:
 if the input like this

`BoardingPoints=['abc']`

`DroppingPoints=['ccd','eef']`

`busType=['Scania Metrolink']`,

`OperatorName=['manu']`

It should returns  these two rows

> {arrivalTime: "10:30 PM"  availableSeats: 23 boardingPoints: [{id:
>   "3882" location: "**abc**" time: "02:30PM"},{id: "3882" location:
>   "xyz" time: "02:30PM"}] busType: "**Scania Metrolink**"
>   operatorName:"sham" commPCT: 8 departureTime: "1:15 PM"
>   droppingPoints: [{id: "3882" location: "dex" time: "02:30PM"},{id:
>   "3882" location: "afg" time: "02:30PM"}] },
>
> {arrivalTime: "10:30 PM" 
>   availableSeats: 23 boardingPoints: [{id: "3882" location: "def" time:
>   "02:30PM"},{id: "3882" location: "jkl" time: "02:30PM"}] busType:
>   "Scania " operatorName:"**manu**" commPCT: 8 departureTime: "1:15 PM"
>   droppingPoints: [{id: "3882" location: "**ccd**" time: "02:30PM"},{id:
>   "3882" location: "**eef**" time: "02:30PM"}] } ]

**Note**

Each input is passed as an array because i need to match multiple values in the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the expected result, it looks like you are looking for the objects that match any of the 4 variables.  Here is the filter that will match them:

```
var bpLocations = ['abc'];
var dpLocations = ['ccdll', 'eef'];
var busTypes = ['Scania Metrolink'];
var operatorNames = ['manu'];

var result = _.filter(inputArray, function(obj) {
    return _(obj.boardingPoints).map('location').intersection(bpLocations).value().length > 0
        || _(obj.droppingPoints).map('location').intersection(dpLocations).value().length > 0
        || _.includes(busTypes, obj.busType)
        || _.includes(operatorNames, obj.operatorName);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ben let me try yr answer

Comment: But the `busType` and  `operatorName` also passed as an array of input like `bploacations` and `dplocations`

Comment: Then just use _.includes() instead of string comparison "===".  Changed the  answer.  Note that I changed busType to busTypes and operatorName to operatorNames since they are now arrays.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35954304/lodash-javascript-dynamic-expression-in-fliter-function-based-on-variable-value  .Please help me ben